# What is wrong with my hash function?

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I'm trying to create a hash table. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 19
#define c1 3
#define c2 5
#define m 3000
int efort;
int h_table[N];

int h(int k, int i)
{
    return (k + i*c1 + i*i*c2) % N;
}
void init()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        h_table[i] = -1;
}
void insert(int k)
{
    int position, i;
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        position = h(k, i);
        printf("\n Position %d \n", position);
        if (h_table[position] == -1)
        {       
            h_table[position] = k;
            printf("Inserted :elem %d at %d \n", h_table[position], position);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            i += 1;
        }
    } while (i != N);
}
void print(int n)
{
    printf("\nTable content: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", h_table[i]);
    }

 }


void test()
 {
    int a[100];
    int b[100];
    init();
    memset(b, -1, 100);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % (3000 + 1 - 2000) + 2000;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++)
    {
        insert(a[i]);
    }
    print(N);
}
 int main()
{   
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Hash ("h") function and "insert" function are took from "Introduction to algorithms" book (Cormen).I don't know what is happening with the h function or insert function. Sometimes it fills completely my array, but sometimes it doesn't. That means it doesn't work good. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Note that `memset(b, -1, 100)` does not set all `b[]` to -1.

Comment: Rather than stopping at `while (i != N)`, keep looking.  Perhaps after `i >= N/2` just look linearly for the next free cell.

Comment: replacing the `memset()` statement with `for(i=0;i<100;i++) b[i]=-1;` does not fix the apparent problem.

Comment: I used something similar to debugger. I used  printf("Position %d",position)  and it was pretty clear for me that the hash function is skipping some values. I can see that it's wrong, but i can't find out why... I need to use a quadratic function of hash :(

Comment: Consider the hash function in 2 parts.  Pre-hash `(k + i*c1 + i*i*c2)` and post-hash `pre_hash()%N`.  You are looking for a `pre_hash(k,i)` with a modulo period of `N` based on `i`.  A _good_ `pre_hash()` would not have such a periodicity - it should be independent of `N, i, k`.  You could use `k+i` to meet this question goal, but that has other weak hash qualities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you are producing repeating values for `position` often enough to prevent `h_table[]` from being populated after only `N` attempts...

The pseudo-random number generator is not guaranteed to produce a set of unique numbers, nor is your `h(...)` function guaranteed to produce a mutually exclusive set of position values.  It is likely that you are generating the same position enough times that you run out of loops before all 19 positions have been generated.  The question *how many times must `h(...)` be called on average before you are likely to get the value of an unused position?* should be answered.  This may help to direct you to the problem.

***As an experiment***, I increased the looping indexes from `N` to `100` in all but the `h(...)` function (so as not to overrun `h_table[]` ).  And as expected the first 5 positions filled immediately.  The next one filled after 3 more tries.  The next one 10 tries later, and so on, until by the end of 100 tries, there were still some unwritten positions.
***On the next run***, all table positions were filled.

2 possible solutions:
1) Modify hash to improve probability of unique values.
2) Increase iterations to populate `h_table`

Answer (score 0):

A `good_hash_function() % N` may repeat itself in `N` re-hashes.  A good hash looks nearly *random* in its output even though it is deterministic.  So in `N` tries it might not loop through all the array elements.

After failing to find a free array element after a number of tries, say N/3 tries, recommend a different approach.  Just look for the next free element.